# Language-agnostic term for typed things that need memory

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic, variables, object

Is there an accepted general term that subsumes the concepts of variables, class instances and arrays? Basically "any typed thing that needs memory". In C++, such a thing is called an *object*, but I'm looking for a more language-agnostic term.

> ### § 1.8 The C++ object model
>
> 1 The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. **An object is a region of storage.**
>   [...]
>   An object can have a name (Clause 3). An object has a storage duration (3.7) which influences its lifetime (3.8). **An object has a type** (3.9).

Comment: If the question is supposed to be language-agnostic, tag it as such and remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @Neil I expect C++ programmers to have stumbled upon the same question before, hence the C++ tag ;-)

Comment: That isn't how tagging works.

Comment: @Neil Then feel free to change the tags.

Comment: @gbn: Not completely sure. Some things might be removed at compile-time and, therefore, not consume memory on runtime. Also, when it comes to C unions, saying a member "needs memory" is ambiguous.

Comment: Oh, there actually is a language-agnostic tag? Cool :)

Comment: Yes indeed - used some 2,800+ times ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance: "Data entity" or "Information entity".

Maybe one could only say "entity" but for me that sounds way too abstract. "Data..." or "information..." adds at least a bit minimum context. "Entity" is separated from "Operation" (functions, procedures, methods) or "Relationship".

Well, no clue, if this is generally accepted.

(But in the end I feel "Entity" only to be another word for "Object", perhaps just without the immediate association to object-oriented programming.)

Answer (score 4):

In languages where most/all things are "first class," such as Lisp or Lua, this would be called a "value."

Comment: And in other kinds of langauge? I think that there in no widely used language-agnostic term.

Comment: @djna I think the problem is that it is good to abstract from the memory model for a language (I am not talking GC, but address modes etc) and therefore many general terms do not depend on the memory. I guess you won't get further than value or variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples all have some things in common, they have a name that one references in a programming language and some corresponding bits in some memory somewhere. But the model of the meaning of that relationship is very tied to the specific language that you are using.

I think that's why a single vocabulary such as "variable" or "class instance" will not be consistent across languages. In my mind there's quite a distinction between even those two terms in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The C99 spec uses the word "object", despite C not being an object oriented language.  Section  3.14 defines 'object' as a 'region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values'.

Comment: In C++ it also has nothing to do with OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Does Object not suit your needs? - I think of "Object" as an abstract idea... a variable that contains data (and thus memory) the structure of which is either unknown or irrelevant.

Comment: In my mind, in languages such as Java, a variable (other than a primtive such as int) does not contain data, it references it. Two variables could reference the same object state.

Comment: That's because Java is a terrible language. :P

Seriously, the reference itself is a valid object. Java just separates user-defined objects from language-defined objects.

Answer (score -1):

It's called a data member.